# VSCode fails to export jupyter notebook to html

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook in VSCode that I'm trying to export to html with the built-in buttons in VSCode, however I keep getting this error that says "Jupyter command `jupyter-nbconvert` not found".

I'm using pip and have pip installed anything jupyter related I can think of: jupyter, jupyterlab , nbconvert, notebook.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue? I'm using Windows 10.

```
> C:\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\Toshiba\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.114305\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py jupyter nbconvert --version
> C:\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\Toshiba\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.114305\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py jupyter nbconvert --version
Error 2020-10-26 10:40:19: Export failed [r [Error]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Toshiba\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.114305\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 26, in <module>
    runpy.run_module(module, run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter.py", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
    raise Exception(
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-nbconvert` not found.
```

Comment: Does it output its version number when you type "jupyter nbconvert --version" in the VSCode terminal? Since the Jupyter notebook function in VSCode is provided by the python extension, it is recommended that you use the latest version of the python extension or try other versions of the python extension.

Comment: When I type that in VSCode terminal I get the following error `jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I have the latest version of the VSCode Python extension installed as well 2020.9.114305. Would it be better to raise an issue on their github?

Comment: You can try "python -m notebook", and try to use different VSCode environments.

Answer (score 3):

1. `pip uninstall nbconvert`
2. run CMD as admin
3. `pip install nbconvert`

I had that same issue, following above steps resolved it. Got this solution from [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4347#issuecomment-824457340)

Answer (score -2):

You'are using jupyter extension, but you didn't install jupyter in your python interpreter. Just 'pip install jupyter', export will work.
If you're using venv or other virtual environment, you should install jupyter there.

Comment: Hi Elliot! Please format your code properly when posting on answers. You can reaad more about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thanks! The solution written by Elliot is perfect.