# Exporting Jupyter notebook doesn't work in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using VSCode with WSL Ubuntu 20.04. I'm trying to export a Jupyter notebook to PDF or HTML in VSCode using the built-in Export feature in the Jupyter extension.
I get this error message: `Jupyter command 'jupyter-nbconvert' not found.`

Things I have tried:

- Changing the interpreter that starts Jupyter in VSCode
- Uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter and nbconvert in the integrated terminal
- Making sure the path where Jupyter is installed is on my PATH

Things I have not tried that were suggested by others in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64535664/vscode-fails-to-export-jupyter-notebook-to-html):

- Uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter and nbconvert in Powershell.
  How would one do this? `pip3 install nbconvert` returns this error: `pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Running `which nbconvert` from the integrated terminal returns nothing. I installed nbconvert via pip3.

Comment: What command are you running that throws that error? Where are you running that command( In Powershell? In your WSL's shell? In Jupyter? In a python shell?). Where did you run `which nbconvert`? Is `nbconvert` installed? If so was it via pip or apt-get or some other way?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the lack of clarity. I made some edits.

Comment: I'm confused now about powershell vs WSL. Where is jupyter and python installed? In Windows or inside whatever distro you are running in WSL? When you go into Powershell and type "wsl" it should drop you into a bash shell inside your wsl install, and I'm assuming in there is where python is installed and where you should submit your `pip3 install nbconvert` command. It's not clear enough to say for sure that's the correct step though.

Comment: Jupyter and Python are installed in Ubuntu 20.04, the distro I'm running in WSL. Thank you for explaining the Powershell part. I tried what you said and it didn't fix the issue. It was suggested as a fix for this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64535664/vscode-fails-to-export-jupyter-notebook-to-html

Answer (score 0):

> pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Try this command to install nbconvert:

```
python -m pip install nbconvert -U
```